# Software to take Picture via iSight after some interval

Tags: macos, camera

I am looking for a software, something like that - http://www.sobolsoft.com/howtouse/automatic-take-webcam.htm, which can take picture after some specified time, for Mac OS X.

If there is any free solution, that is much preferred.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* Photo Booth, included with Mac OS X, has a time-lapse mode, but I can't check because I'm on a Mac without a camera currently.

If it doesn't, you can try an application called [Gawker](http://gawker.sourceforge.net/Information.html), which bills itself as having a time-lapse mode.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageSnap](http://www.iharder.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) recently added the ability to take a picture at a specified interval.

You could then stitch the images together into a movie using 'mencoder' or a number of other utilities.