# Mac OS X software that takes time lapse photos using built in webcam?

Tags: macos, mac, webcam, osx-lion, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to take Picture via iSight after some interval](https://superuser.com/questions/173815/software-to-take-picture-via-isight-after-some-interval)

I'd like to periodically take pictures of myself while I work.  Is there a time lapse application that works on Mac OS X that (unobtrusively) takes photos and say, saves them into a folder?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate; I wasn't looking for software that took a picture after an interval, but repeatedly, as well.  Which is to say, not just a delay, but actual [time lapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_lapse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageSnap](http://www.iharder.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) recently added the ability to take a picture at a specified interval.

You could then stitch the images together into a movie using 'mencoder' or a number of other utilities.

Comment: It looks like you've been promoting this product on several questions. If you are affiliated with the product, please make sure to read the section of our [FAQ#promotion] regarding self-promotion. You are required to disclose any affiliation with products you recommend on Super User.

Comment: I'm only promoting it in the sense that it would solve this question and the linked duplicate. I'm not affiliated with the development of the linked FOSS tool. In the future I'll make clear the lack of affiliation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The posts were automatically flagged because they were identical, which is a sign of spamming. I see now that you were just adding the info to duplicates. For future reference, you don't need to answer the duplicate too - just answer the original question, and the duplicate will eventually be closed. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate; I wasn't looking for software that took a picture after an interval, but repeatedly, as well. Which is to say, not just a delay, but actual time lapse.